# Groupby one year interval with the start as first datapoint of the series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, intervals

How can I group a time series with 1 year intervals such that the start of the first interval is the first datapoint and the new series is labeled by that starting point?

E.g. here I have a series that starts at `2000-01-11`, so the first interval should have all datapoints between `2000-01-11` and `2001-01-10`, second `2001-01-11` and `2002-01-10` etc; the labels of the new series 2000-01-11, 2001-01-11 etc?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = pd.date_range('2000-01-11', '2022-02-10', freq='D')
t = pd.Series(index=i, data=np.random.randint(0,100,len(i)))
print(t)

t.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1Y', origin='start', label='left')).mean()
```

This codes seems to bin at the start of the year and label by the end of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pd.cut` and group by these categories:

```py
x = pd.cut(
    i,
    pd.date_range(start="1999-12-31", end="2022-02-10", freq="12M")
    + pd.offsets.DateOffset(11),
    right=False,
    include_lowest=True
)

out = t.groupby(x).mean()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[2000-01-11, 2001-01-11)    51.174863
[2001-01-11, 2002-01-11)    48.197260
[2002-01-11, 2003-01-11)    49.400000
[2003-01-11, 2004-01-11)    50.509589
[2004-01-11, 2005-01-11)    49.680328
[2005-01-11, 2006-01-11)    48.334247
[2006-01-11, 2007-01-11)    47.882192
[2007-01-11, 2008-01-11)    51.405479
[2008-01-11, 2009-01-11)    50.437158
[2009-01-11, 2010-01-11)    49.520548
[2010-01-11, 2011-01-11)    48.591781
[2011-01-11, 2012-01-11)    51.643836
[2012-01-11, 2013-01-11)    51.084699
[2013-01-11, 2014-01-11)    50.334247
[2014-01-11, 2015-01-11)    51.109589
[2015-01-11, 2016-01-11)    48.230137
[2016-01-11, 2017-01-11)    49.691257
[2017-01-11, 2018-01-11)    47.326027
[2018-01-11, 2019-01-11)    48.728767
[2019-01-11, 2020-01-11)    47.947945
[2020-01-11, 2021-01-11)    48.866120
[2021-01-11, 2022-01-11)    49.268493
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I originally misread the question.

`origin` doesn't work with non-fixed frequencies such as years.

This would work with fixed frequencies like days:

```
t.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='365.25D', origin='start_day', label='left')).mean()
```

Output:

```
2000-01-11 00:00:00    49.991803
2001-01-10 06:00:00    46.619178
2002-01-10 12:00:00    49.205479
2003-01-10 18:00:00    51.326027
2004-01-11 00:00:00    50.131148
2005-01-10 06:00:00    49.093151
2006-01-10 12:00:00    52.780822
2007-01-10 18:00:00    49.202740
2008-01-11 00:00:00    53.237705
2009-01-10 06:00:00    51.936986
2010-01-10 12:00:00    48.663014
2011-01-10 18:00:00    48.175342
2012-01-11 00:00:00    50.117486
2013-01-10 06:00:00    48.838356
2014-01-10 12:00:00    49.520548
2015-01-10 18:00:00    47.997260
2016-01-11 00:00:00    51.068306
2017-01-10 06:00:00    47.731507
2018-01-10 12:00:00    46.290411
2019-01-10 18:00:00    47.753425
2020-01-11 00:00:00    48.046448
2021-01-10 06:00:00    52.131507
2022-01-10 12:00:00    55.032258
Freq: 8766H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The index from the second row still reverts to the first day of the year no?

Comment: @not_speshal oh, I misread the question, I thought OP wanted to have the first day of each group as label

Comment: `origin` doesn't work with years, this would work with `t.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='365D', origin='start_day', label='left')).mean()`